# Magento PopUpAjaxCart Does Not Show the Options For Configurable Products

Tags: javascript, php, magento, magento-1.9

I have configurable products that I want the end user to select options from.

While the popup with the id `popUpAjaxCart` appears, but there are no options available to select.

[image]

Things i have tried:

1. Fixing the configurable swatches
2. Trying to edit the phtml file
3. Trying to edit the js file at *public_html/theme/js/magiccart/ajaxcart.js*

Note: I have a theme so magiccart is the name of the theme folder.

Comment: Might be better off on: https://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: posted there as well. Im trying to reach as many people as i can